# Fetch Thumbnail from Video URL using SDWebImage

Tags: ios, swift, video, sdwebimage

I need to fetch thumbnail from a video URL to display in ImageView that is in a UITableViewCell.

I can get thumbnail using this method but it takes lots of resource and hence the tableview scrolling lags and stops for the time cellForRowAtIndexPath is called.

This is the method.

```
func createThumbnailOfVideoFromFileURL(videoURL: String) -> UIImage? {
    let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(string: videoURL)!)
    let assetImgGenerate = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    let time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(1), 100)
    do {
        let img = try assetImgGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
        let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: img)
        return thumbnail
    } catch {
        return UIImage(named: "ico_placeholder")
    }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest me an alternative to use SDWebImage so that the images go to the cache and are not fetched everytime UITableView delegates are called.
Kindly suggest any other approach if i m wrong.

Comment: Anyone there for any help?

Comment: Did you get any help?

Comment: Hey, Did you get any help? I am facing same issue. Thanks

Comment: You can use Kingfisher for the same, a good alternate...please find the link :-**https://stackoverflow.com/a/72564375/14180967**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the above method as it is and cached the images in an array of UIImage and made a check in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` that if image exists at that particular index then use that else fetch the image in background.

Answer (score 0):

Not using SDWebImage but this code works like a charm

```
func getThumbnailFromUrl(_ url: String?, _ completion: @escaping ((_ image: UIImage?)->Void)) {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: (url ?? "")) else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
            let assetImgGenerate = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            
            let time = CMTimeMake(value: 2, timescale: 1)
            do {
                let img = try assetImgGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
                let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: img)
                completion(thumbnail)
            } catch let error{
                print("Error :: ", error)
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage

```
self.getThumbnailFromUrl(video.url.description) { (image) in
     //Use image where you want to use
}
```